# How do I "spray" an image properly?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In Team Fortress 2 how do I "spray an image"? I thought that I had to download (or make) the spray, then within the game bind a key, or something like that.

I also wanted to know if I can use sprays on all servers or not. Is it only one spray per round or something?

Comment: Well that is how to do it in game. It does not address this: "I also wanted to know if I can use sprays on all servers or not. Is it only one spray per round or something?"

Comment: Sorry, I read the title - if you have multiple questions, you should normally split them up into separate questions. However whilst I'm here, I have never come across a server that restricts the use of sprays, so I do not know whether it is possible. You can spray multiple times, the old spray will disappear and a new one will be placed (i.e. you can't tile the walls with copies of your sprays). There is a cooldown timer between your use of the spray, it seems to be around 10 seconds, but I'm not sure of the exact number.

Comment: It is possible to restrict or ban sprays on a server.  I've also worked on plugins to the server where you can detect the user who sprayed a spray, and/or move or respray anyone's spray on a server.  Few servers go to this extreme, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit to how many times you can spray a spray, though there is a cooldown in between sprays. Sprays last until you spray elsewhere, which means you cannot tile a wall with your spray. Furthermore, some servers have it set so that no one can spray.

Consult your options panel for the spray keybinding. The default is bound to "T".

Installing a spray is kind of a hassle if you've never done it before, check out this page: http://tf2.gamebanana.com/tuts/4488

1. Find your image, it must be square the following sizes are acceptable: 64*64 128*128 256*256.
2. Download VTFedit.
3. With VTFedit, Import your own .JPG,.BMP, etc... and convert it to a .VTF file (Valve Texture File)
4. Now place the .VTF file in: (your dir)\Steam\steamapps(your username)\team fortress 2\tf\materials\VGUI\logos
5. To fix the quick view appearing blank copy the same .VTF also in: (your dir)\Steam\steamapps(your username)\team fortress 2\tf\materials\VGUI\logos\UI
6. In game, go to the options and click import the spray and browse for it in the \logos folder (not the UI folder!) and validate. (this will create a VMT file near your VTF)